# siteproblem in rewriting site urls

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

i have problems in rewriting url's in my site
when i rewrite url's site styles dont work

i write this code in htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !Resources/css/(.*)
RewriteRule ^/?(index.(html|php|java|jsp|asp))?$ controller.php
RewriteRule ^LoadPage/(.*) controller.php?LoadedPage=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^Admin/(.*) controller.php?Page=Admin&Section=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*) controller.php?Page=$1 [QSA]
```

but when i write this url for example:

```
localhost/sitename/Admin/Users
```

the page Users successfully rendered , but without style !

Comment: Could you add the directory structure to the question? It's hard to know where your css files are related to the other files. Also, how are they referenced in the generated page?

Comment: @nader so my answer has not helped? what problem are you still having?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find a good answer over here
[.htaccess](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

You can also redirect everything that is not an actual file directory to your controller like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . controller.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: ok so what kind of error are you getting? cause with this if your css doesnt load it means its not in the correct folder